# XAMPP - Invalid access memory location

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp

When I start XAMPP Apache does not start and when I check the XAMPP shell, I see this error:

> cannot load C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll into server: invalid access memory location

When I comment it out, the Apache process starts, but when I try to load my WordPress files, the server only loads the HTML and PHP codes, the CSS files are missing.

When I check the Apache admin panel, I get the following error:

> Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(

This is what i saw when i open my WordPress File "' . __( 'Welcome to your WordPress Dashboard! This is the screen you will see when you log in to your site, and gives you access to all the site management features of WordPress. You can get help for any screen by clicking the Help tab above the screen title.' ) . '
'; $screen = get_current_screen(); $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'overview', 'title' => __( 'Overview' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); // Help tabs $help = '
' . __( 'The left-hand navigation menu provides links to all of the WordPress administration screens, with submenu items displayed on hover. You can minimize this menu to a narrow icon strip by clicking on the Collapse Menu arrow at the bottom.' ) . '

'; $help .= '
' . __( 'Links in the Toolbar at the top of the screen connect your dashboard and the front end of your site, and provide access to your profile and helpful WordPress information.' ) . '

'; $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'help-navigation', 'title' => __( 'Navigation' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); $help = '
' . __( 'You can use the following controls to arrange your Dashboard screen to suit your workflow. This is true on most other administration screens as well.' ) . '

'; $help .= '
' . __( 'Screen Options — Use the Screen Options tab to choose which Dashboard boxes to show.' ) . '

'; $help .= '
' . __( 'Drag and Drop — To rearrange the boxes, drag and drop by clicking on the title bar of the selected box and releasing when you see a gray dotted-line rectangle appear in the location you want to place the box.' ) . '

'; $help .= '
' . __( 'Box Controls — Click the title bar of the box to expand or collapse it. Some boxes added by plugins may have configurable content, and will show a “Configure” link in the title bar if you hover over it.' ) . '

'; $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'help-layout', 'title' => __( 'Layout' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); $help = '
' . __( 'The boxes on your Dashboard screen are:' ) . '

'; if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) $help .= '
' . __( 'At A Glance — Displays a summary of the content on your site and identifies which theme and version of WordPress you are using.' ) . '

'; $help .= '
' . __( 'Activity — Shows the upcoming scheduled posts, recently published posts, and the most recent comments on your posts and allows you to moderate them.' ) . '

'; if ( is_blog_admin() && current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) $help .= '
' . __( "Quick Draft — Allows you to create a new post and save it as a draft. Also displays links to the 5 most recent draft posts you've started." ) . '

'; if ( ! is_multisite() && current_user_can( 'install_plugins' ) ) $help .= '
' . sprintf( /* translators: %s: WordPress Planet URL */ __( 'WordPress News — Latest news from the official WordPress project, the WordPress Planet, and popular plugins.' ), __( 'https://planet.wordpress.org/' ) ) . '

'; else $help .= '
' . sprintf( /* translators: %s: WordPress Planet URL */ __( 'WordPress News — Latest news from the official WordPress project and the WordPress Planet.' ), __( 'https://planet.wordpress.org/' ) ) . '

'; if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) $help .= '
' . __( 'Welcome — Shows links for some of the most common tasks when setting up a new site.' ) . '

'; $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'help-content', 'title' => __( 'Content' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); unset( $help ); $screen->set_help_sidebar( '
' . __( 'For more information:' ) . '

' . '
' . __( 'Documentation on Dashboard' ) . '

' . '
' . __( 'Support Forums' ) . '

' ); include( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/admin-header.php' ); ?>
user_email != get_option( 'admin_email' ) ); if ( $hide ) $classes .= ' hidden'; ?> "

As you can see its only the back-end that i can see.

Comment: Commented it out of where?

Comment: It should not have been in the httpd.conf or the php.ini

Comment: I dont think you CSS issue is anything to do with  php5ts.dll

Comment: @RiggsFolly i commented it out in the httpd-xampp.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you try to load php5.dll compiled for Apache x64 while your php is x86, and vice versa.

Make sure that your apache and php are both x64 or both x86 and preferably compiled with the same VC.

If the problem persist comment these two lines in "\XAMPP\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf":

```
# LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php5ts.dll"
# LoadModule php5_module modules/php5apache2_2.dll
```

then restart Apache.

If it change nothing, just upgrade your PHP version., in my case the same error occurred with PHP5.5.0.0, but not with PHP5.4.16.0.

Comment: I commented the two lines out, the Apache worked but  when i tried to load my WordPress file, it only loaded this back-end codes. : _ 'Welcome to your WordPress Dashboard! This is the screen you will see when you log in to your site, and gives you access to all the site management features of WordPress. You can get help for any screen by clicking the Help tab above the screen title.' ) . ' '; $screen = get_current_screen(); $screen->add_help_tab( array( 'id' => 'overview', 'title' => __( 'Overview' ), 'content' => $help, ) ); // Help tabs $help = ' ' . __